# Java Applet GUI

Tags: java, applet

Is there any program with a Java applet GUI designer?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [NetBeans](http://netbeans.org/) to build Java GUIs.  Check out a [tutorial here](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17409_01/javase/tutorial/javabeans/nb/index.html).

Comment: The 54 MB version or the first link on the left should be more than enough for you to get started.

Answer (score 0):

Netbeans or JBuilder. =)

Answer (score 0):

[netbeans](http://netbeans.org/downloads/index.html).

download any version that supports Java SE, and is suitable for your OS and platform